# What's the most efficient way to compare 2 numbers (16bit) bit by bit in Python?

Tags: python

I wonder what would be the most efficient way to compare 2 number (16bit) bit by bit in python? The order of the comparison does not matter.

In pseudo code I need something like this:

```
IF NUMBER1_BIT1 !=  NUMBER2_BIT1    THEN do something
IF NUMBER1_BIT2 !=  NUMBER2_BIT2    THEN do something 
IF NUMBER1_BIT3 !=  NUMBER2_BIT3    THEN do something 
…..
IF NUMBER1_BIT16 !=  NUMBER2_BIT16 THEN do something
```

This part of my program will be executed a lot so I want to be as efficient as python can allow it.

Comment: Is "do something" always the same? I would say as soon as you want to do something "bit by bit" you are way off the "most efficient way" already.

Comment: If the bits are equal, then the numbers are equal - or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: [Python IF...ELIF...ELSE Statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Comment: `NUMBER1 ^ NUMBER2` gives you a single number with bits set where the two numbers differ. Iterating over those bits, though, is a little tricker.

Comment: What's the most efficient depends on the size of the operands. Probably Numpy will be a lot faster than native Python if you have enough comparisons that it actually makes sense to care about efficiency of this particular operation at all, but that's a huge dependency to pull in just for that. If it's just 16 bits and a handful of numbers, you probably don't need to worry about speed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xor` and `and` operators:

```
num3 = num1 ^ num2
if num3 & 1: # bits 0 are different
    ...
if num3 & 2: # bits 1 are different
    ...
if num3 & 4: # bits 2 are different
    ...
```

Comment: Nice one.  Might expand with `for i in range(17): num3 & 1 << i`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert this into a switch-statement using a helper function:

```
def bitSwitch(v): yield lambda b: v & (1<<b)
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
for case in bitSwitch(number1 ^ number2):
    if case(0): 
       # do something ...

    if case(1):
       # do something else ...

    if case(2):
       # do some other thing ...

    if case(3):
       # do something different ...

    ...

    if case(15):
       # do that last thing ...
```

*To be more efficient, you could replace `v & (1<<b)` with just `v & b` in the switch function and use the pre-computed powers of 2 in the `case(..)` calls:  `case(1):`  `case(2)` `case(4)` `case(8)` ...  At that point napuzba's solution will be better because it does the same thing with less function call overhead.*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are creating a bit mask. It is very common to see this done in C with 32 bit numbers and each bit is represented by a constant.

The cool thing about this method is that the mask will only produce some output if the bit is set in the input, otherwise the output will be 0.

Anyways, this is not C; this is python, so we can use the [`bin(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) method to convert each number to binary string, then compare each character in the string.

```
b_num1 = bin(num1).replace('0b', '')
b_num2 = bin(num2).replace('0b', '')

for i in range(num1.bit_length()):
    if b_num1[i] != b_num2[i]:
        pass # do something
    ...
```

---

Edit

In python3, we can use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to create the binary numbers:

```
b_num1 = f'{num1:b}'
b_num2 = f'{num2:b}'
```

Comment: More of a question than a methodology challenge: Is it not (more) inefficient to make repetitive calls the `bin()` and `replace()` functions than to use bitwise operators / bit shifting? Especially if there are many numbers to compare. Surely this adds an unnecessary layer of abstraction.